# Pandas: replace values in column with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
city_reg     city_live   reg_region    live_region 
 Moscow         Tver        77            69
 Tambov         Tumen'      86            86
```

I need to replace values in `city_reg` to values from `city_live` if `reg_region == live_region`

I try to use

```
df.loc[df.reg_region == df.live_region, 'city_reg'] = df['city_live']
```

but it returnes

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) which working with duplicated indices very nice:

```
#create duplicated indices for test
df.index = [0,0]
print (df)
  city_reg city_live  reg_region  live_region
0   Moscow      Tver          77           69
0   Tambov    Tumen'          86           86

df['city_reg'] = df['city_reg'].mask(df.reg_region == df.live_region,  df['city_live'])
```

Or:

```
df['city_reg'] = np.where(df.reg_region == df.live_region,  df['city_reg'], df['city_live'])
```

---

```
print (df)
  city_reg city_live  reg_region  live_region
0   Moscow      Tver          77           69
0   Tumen'    Tumen'          86           86
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mask = df.reg_region == df.live_region
df.loc[mask, 'city_reg'] = df.loc[mask, 'city_live']

#   city_reg city_live  reg_region  live_region
# 0   Moscow      Tver          77           69
# 1   Tumen'    Tumen'          86           86
```

The reason this works is that the indices are aligned between the left and right hand sides of the assignment when you apply the same mask.