# In pandas, how to replace values matching a condition with a value from the names of their columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm writing a function that takes as input a dataframe and a "mask".
The dataframe's assumed to have multiindex columns such as
`("some string", 0.4)`: pairs where the second object is numeric.
The mask is intended to be something like `df < 2`, `df >= 4`, etc.

The output should be a new table where
every value that doesn't match the mask is left alone, and
every value that does is replaced by the number of the name of its column.

NaNs in the input should be left alone
(unless of course the mask is something like `df.isna()`).

This is what I've come up with
(assume this is in a file called `mytable.py`):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {
    ("A", 0.2): [4.0, 1.0, np.nan],
    ("B", 0.6): [0.0, np.nan, 4.0],
    ("C", 0.7): [0.0, 5.0, 1.0],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def replaced_with_colname(table, mask):
    series1 = (table[col][mask[col]] for col in table.columns)
    series2 = (s.apply(lambda x: s.name[1]) for s in series1)
    t2 = table.copy()
    for s in series2:
        t2.update(s)
    return t2
```

An example:

```bash
$ python3 -i mytable.py
```

```py
>>> df
     A    B    C
   0.2  0.6  0.7
0  4.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  NaN  5.0
2  NaN  4.0  1.0
>>> replaced_with_colname(df, df>2)
     A    B    C
   0.2  0.6  0.7
0  0.2  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  NaN  0.7
2  NaN  0.6  1.0
```

It seems to do the job, but it seems convoluted and probably slow,
though I didn't benchmark it.
My question is:
*is there a (more) "vectorized", idiomatic way of doing it?
Using more pandas methods and fewer for-loops?*

Similar questions that helped me, and
why they're not exactly what I'm trying to do:

- [Pandas: replace values in column with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48869292/5737038)
  My replacements come from the column names, not the "body" of the table.
- [How to replace a value in a pandas dataframe with column name based on a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37032043/5737038)
  The difference is that I'm replacing not a specific value, but all that fit a condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a perfect use case for `np.where`: if `mask` is `True` returns the second level index values else keep as it.

```
def replaced_with_colname(table, mask):
    data = np.where(mask, df.columns.levels[1], df)
    return pd.DataFrame(data, index=table.index, columns=table.columns)
```

Usage:

```
>>> replaced_with_colname(df, df>2)
     A    B    C
   0.2  0.6  0.7
0  0.2  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  NaN  0.7
2  NaN  0.6  1.0

>>> replaced_with_colname(df, df.isna())
     A    B    C
   0.2  0.6  0.7
0  4.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  0.6  5.0
2  0.2  4.0  1.0

>>> replaced_with_colname(df, (0<=df) & (df<=1) | df.isna())
     A    B    C
   0.2  0.6  0.7
0  4.0  0.6  0.7
1  0.2  0.6  5.0
2  0.2  4.0  0.7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can approach this by using [`pandas.Index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) :

```
out = (
        df
          .gt(2)
          .mul(df.columns.get_level_values(1))
          .mask(lambda d: [d[col].eq(0) for col in d.columns])
          .combine_first(df)
      )
```

The *comparison operators* (`eq, ne, le, lt, ge, gt`) are equivalent to (`==, !=, <=, <, >=, >`).

​Output :

```
print(out)

     A    B    C
   0.2  0.6  0.7
0  0.2  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  NaN  0.7
2  NaN  0.6  1.0
```

If you need a custom function :

```
def replace_with_colname(table, cond):
    out = (
            df[cond]
              .mul(df.columns.get_level_values(1))
              .mask(lambda d: [d[col].eq(0) for col in d.columns])
              .combine_first(df)
          )
    return out
```

Comment: Hm, after changing `df.gt(2)` to `mask` (because the condition should be given by the function call, not hardcoded), it seems this usually works but sometimes replaces NaNs with the column names. For example, with `replace_with_colname(df, df<=1)` the NaN at iloc (2, 0) becomes 0.2.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. `print(replace_with_colname(df, df<=1).iat[2,0])` gives `nan`. I updated my answer with the function used.